# Como pegar filho de uma div pai?

Tags: javascript

Seguinte, tenho uma série de Lis criadas dinamicamente. 
O que preciso fazer com JS puro é simplesmente achar o filho da div pai.

Funciona assim: 
Quando uma data tem uma hora indisponível o sistema avisa.

A data é i ID pai, e os filhos são IDs em horas.

Com Js PURO (estou aprendendo por isso quero puro e não Jquery).

Como fazer para percorrer e achar o ID filho ?

```html
<li style="display:none;" id="12-05-2016">Para o dia: 12-05-2016
    
    <ul><li  id="08:00"> Esta hora esta indisponivel: 08:00</li></ul>

    <ul><li  id="09:00"> Esta hora esta indisponivel: 09:00</li></ul>

</li>

<li style="display:none;" id="13-05-2016">Para o dia: 13-05-2016

</li>
```

Comment: Como sabes o que procurar? Vais procurar o elemento filho por `id`? e de onde sabes se deves procurar por `08:00` ou por `09:00`?

Comment: Essa parte não é problema.

Comment: Com Js eu á pego os elementos. 
Da data e hora.

Só preciso comparar a data (id) com a hora (id filha)

Comment: Não percebi a tua resposta. O que procuras nos elementos filhos? Se queres saber todos podes usar `elemento.children`. Se procuras __um__, específico, o que é que procuras nele? pois nesse caso pode haver uma resposta mais acertada.

Comment: Sempre será um especifico.

Comment: @Uriel Muito mal feito essa relação de Id. Pode melhorar colocando algo estatico, exemplo "data_12-05-2016" , "hora_08:00" .

Comment: @Uriel dá uma olhada de novo às minhas perguntas aqui nos comentários. Percebeste o que procuro esclarecer e que não está claro para mim na tua pergunta?

Comment: Sergio, a pergunta é muito simples. 

Eu quero verificar se uma data tem uma hora á dentro. 

A data é uma ID a hora que esta dentro tbm é. 

Via JS eu pego o campo data e o seu valor. 
Depois pego do campo hora o seu valor. 

tenho cada um em sua variavel.

Comment: @Uriel então tens numa variável a hora que queres e precisas de encontrar o elemento filho que tem essa hora como `id` é isso?

Comment: O problema foi resolvido

Comment: @Uriel ok, ótimo. Eu ainda acho que há duvidas e que podias perceber melhor o teu problema. Se quiseres aprender e perceber o problema melhor dá feedback às perguntas de pessoas experientes que te querem ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que você tem como obter o ID, segue uma solução proposta.
Vale ressaltar que no exemplo, eu mudei o atributo *display:none* para *display:block*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li style="display:block;" id="12-05-2016">Para o dia: 12-05-2016
      <ul><li  id="08:00"> Esta hora esta indisponivel: 08:00</li></ul>

      <ul><li  id="09:00"> Esta hora esta indisponivel: 09:00</li></ul>
   </li>

    <li style="display:block;" id="13-05-2016">Para o dia: 13-05-2016>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Obtém o elemento PAI */
    var elem = document.getElementById("12-05-2016");

     /* Obtém os elementos FILHOS (childNode) filtrando pela ul */
    var subElem = elem.getElementsByTagName("ul");

    /* Apresentar cada item dentro do ChildNode (FILHO)*/
    for(i = 0; i < subElem.length; i++)
      console.log(subElem[i].getElementsByTagName("li")[0]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Fiz uma mudança e resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

Uriel seguinte, se você for repetir as horas por exemplo, 08:00 estiver em duas diferentes datas eu aconselho passar essas horas que você quer como classe, ai então utilizar:

```
var pai = document.getElementById('12-05-2016');
var filhos = pai.getElementsByClassName('08:00');
```

Pois utilizar o id significa que esse será único (pelo menos é o que se espera). E se não repetir basta utilizar o próprio `getElementById`.